# GeoFire query in Firebase Realtime Database is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am using GeoFire to add and retrieve location data in Firebase Realtime Database in my React Native app. The data is added successfully using the `addDataToGeofire()` function, but when I try to retrieve the data using the `getDataFromGeofire()` function and query it using `geoFire.query`, I get the following error message:

> "ERROR [Error: Firebase Database (${JSCORE_VERSION}) INTERNAL ASSERT
> FAILED: Unknown node type] WARN [@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING:
> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered
> on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "g" at / to your security
> rules for better performance. ERROR [TypeError: t.split is not a
> function. (In 't.split("/")', 't.split' is undefined)] ERROR [Error:
> Firebase Database (${JSCORE_VERSION}) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Unknown
> node type] WARN [@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an
> unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the
> client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "g" at / to your security rules
> for better performance]"

The `geoFire.get()` function is working fine and returns the location data for a specific key. However, the `geoFire.query()` function is not working at all. I have checked the data structure in the Firebase Realtime Database and it looks like this after adding data with `geoFire.set()`:

> { "-NP4heZ1yLXk96HiScqH": { ".priority": "u2mw1ze54y", "g":
> "u2mw1ze54y", "l": [
> 40.502686,
> 19.0655181 ] } }

I am not sure what is causing the error in the `geoFire.query()` function. Can anyone help me with this issue? Here is my code:

**firebasehelper.tsx**:

```
public async addDataToGeofire(){
  const geoFire = await new GeoFire(this.firebaseRef);

  const requestId = "-NP4heZ1yLXk96HiScqH";
  const latitude = 40.502686;
  const longitude = 19.0655181;

  await geoFire.set(requestId, [latitude, longitude])
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`Coordinates successfully added to the key: ${requestId}`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`An error occurred while adding the coordinate" ${error}`);
    });
}

public async getDataFromGeofire(){
  const geoFire = await new GeoFire(this.firebaseRef);

  await geoFire.get("-NP4heZ1yLXk96HiScqH").then(function(location) {
    if (location === null) {
      console.log("Provided key is not in GeoFire");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Provided key has a location of " + location);
    }
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  });

  const geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: [40.502686, 19.0655181],
    radius: 100
  });

  const onReadyRegistration = geoQuery.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("GeoQuery has loaded and fired all other events for initial data");
  });
}
```

**app.tsx:**

```
    constructor(){
  this.someMethod();    
}

async someMethod(){
  await databaseHelper.addDataToGeofire().then(async () => {await databaseHelper.getDataFromGeofire()});
}
```

the whole output:

> LOG  Coordinates successfully added to the key: -NP4heZ1yLXk96HiScqH
> LOG  Provided key has a location of 40.502686,19.0655181  ERROR
> [Error: Firebase Database (${JSCORE_VERSION}) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED:
> Unknown node type]  WARN  [2023-02-26T19:54:41.545Z]
> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your
> data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding
> ".indexOn": "g" at / to your security rules for better performance.
> ERROR  [TypeError: t.split is not a function. (In 't.split("/")',
> 't.split' is undefined)]  ERROR  [Error: Firebase Database
> (${JSCORE_VERSION}) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Unknown node type]  WARN
> [2023-02-26T19:54:41.698Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING:
> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered
> on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "g" at / to your security
> rules for better performance.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you're querying data at a path for which you didn't [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#defining_data_indexes) your in your database's rules.

If you really stored the data directly under the root (that is uncommon, but not impossible) the index would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...,
    ".indexOn": "g"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, the geoQuery.on() functions are now displaying data from the server. One error and one warning disappeared.
Only the following error remains: "[TypeError: t.split is not a function. (In 't.split("/")', 't.split' is undefined)]"
If I call geoQuery.cancel() immediately after the geoQuery.on functions, there will be no error, but I don't want to cancel it right away. What could be causing the error?

Comment: That seems like a separate error and (given that the other message disappeared with the fix from my answer) with its own cause, so I recommend posting it as a separate question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)